# Animating a PNG in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, png

I am currently busy coding a game in javascript as a fun project. I ran into a snag that I can't seem to figure out.
I have a png of a
[shop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9qI5.png) that I am trying to add as a background element, there will be no interaction with it, simply for esthetic purposes.

---

> This is how I import the asset/png and get it in position.

```
const shop = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: 850,
    y: 425
  },
  imageSrc: './Assets/Herb Shop.png',
  scale: 2,
  frameMax: 5
})
```

> I then call my class Sprite() where I determine the size of the
> png(width, height) and determine how to crop each section of the
> image.

```
//Element Creation
class Sprite {
  constructor({ position, imageSrc, scale = 1, frameMax = 1 }) {
    this.position = position
    this.height = 150
    this.width = 50
    this.image = new Image()
    this.image.src = imageSrc
    this.scale = scale
    this.frameMax = frameMax
    this.frameCurrent = 0
    this.frameElapsed = 0
    this.framesHold = 5
  }

  //create Background Elements
  createSprite() {
    c.drawImage(
      this.image,
      this.frameCurrent * (this.image.width / this.frameMax),
      0,
      this.image.width / this.frameMax,
      this.image.height,
      this.position.x,
      this.position.y,
      (this.image.width / this.frameMax) * this.scale,
      this.image.height * this.scale
    )
  }

  //Update Class
  update() {
    this.createSprite();
    this.frameElapsed++
    if(this.frameElapsed % this.framesHold === 0){
      if(this.frameCurrent < this.frameMax -1){
        this.frameCurrent++
      }else {
        this.frameCurrent = 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> And then I call the const shop to execute the command

```
    function animate() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      //console.log('animate');
      c.fillStyle = "black";
      c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      background.update()
      shop.update()
      player1.update()
      player2.update()
}
```

---

My question: How can I iterate through the different frames if they are stacked on top of eachother like in the image I attached? This code works perfectly if I use an image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Kqr.png)

Comment: You'll need to track rows as well, otherwise you'll just loop through the top row over and over.  I would use a colMax and rowMax, then multiply them together  to get your frameMax.   Then as you check which position, you can use col for X and row for Y.

Comment: okey let me try giving that a shot tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion @JonathanKnoll :)